# setDate() set the wrong date on 31st?

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

This is very weird I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have a function to grab the date (i.e in this format: `06/24/2011`), here's the function:

```
function checkDate(input){
    var d = new Date();
    var dspl = input.split("/");

    if(dspl.length != 3)
        return NaN;

    d.setDate(dspl[1]);

    d.setMonth(Number(dspl[0])-1);

    if(dspl[2].length == 2)
        d.setYear("20"+(dspl[2]+""));
    else if(dspl[2].length == 4)
        d.setYear(dspl[2]);
    else
        return NaN;

    var dt = jsToMsDate(new Date(d));
    return dt;
}
```

If I enter any date of the month, it would parse the date correctly, but if I enter 31st, i.e `"01/31/2011"`, then it would turn into `"01/01/2011"`. I'm not sure what to do and not really sure where the problem might be.

Comment: Have you checked what the `new Date(d)` at the end is doing v.s. your `jsToMsDate()` function? Could be JS is working fine but your jsToMs function is broken

Comment: I've tried that, still displaying the 1st instead of 31st.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript's `Date` objects allow you to give invalid combinations of months and days; they automagically correct those for you (so for instance, if you set the day of the month to 31 when the month is June, it automatically makes it July 1st). That means if you set the fields individually, you can run into situations where that automagic correction gets in your way.

In your case, if you're going to set all three of those fields, you're better off using the form of the `Date` constructor that accepts them as arguments:

```
var dt = new Date(year, month, day);
```

(If you want hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds, you can add them as parameters as well.)

So looking at your code, an off-the-cuff update:

```
function checkDate(input){
    var year, month, day, d, dt;
    var dspl = input.split("/");

    if(dspl.length != 3)
        return NaN;

    year  = parseInt(dspl[2], 10);
    month = parseInt(dspl[0], 10) - 1;
    day   = parseInt(dspl[1], 10);
    if (isNaN(year) || isNaN(month) || isNaN(day)) {
        return NaN;
    }

    if (year < 100) {
        year += 2000;
    }

    d = new Date(year, month, day);

    var dt = jsToMsDate(d);
    return dt;
}
```

Some other notes on that update:

- It's best to use `parseInt` to parse numbers from end users, and to always specify the radix (10 for decimal). *(No, `parseInt` is not slower than `Number` or the unary `+` trick. People assume it is, but [it isn't](http://jsperf.com/str-to-number-perf).)*
- No need to muck about with strings to add 2000 to years given with only two digits. But you can if you like. Note I weakened the validation there, allowing one-digit years for (say) 2001 and three-digit years for (say) 300 AD. So if you need it to be that strong, you'll need to readjust that.
- No need to feed the date instance into `new Date()` again.

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the month **before** setting the day (or as Marc B points out in his comment, use the `Date(yearval, monthval, dayval)` constructor).

When you create a `Date` object, it defaults to the current date.  At the time of writing that's in June, so when you try to set the day to 31 it wraps.

...And because of similar behaviour in leap years, you should set the year before setting the month or day.

(It's a good job you developed this code in June rather than in July - the bug would have lurked undiscovered until September, and it would probably have been your users that found it rather than you.  :-)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my code... `d.setDate(dspl[1] + 1);` was something that I experiences around to see if I'm doing something wrong. Edited my code.

Comment: Another option is to do `d = new Date(yearval, monthval, dayval)` instead of doing the seperate `.set...()` calls. Do it in a single call gets around these wrapping issues.

Comment: @Saxman: @T.J. Crowder's answer is way better than mine - you should accept that one instead.

Answer (score 2):

**Right hierarchy is set year, then Month and at last add the Day.
This will return the exact date that you added.**

```js
function checkDate() {

  //Wrong order-  will return 1 May 2016
  var start = new Date();
  start.setDate(31);
  start.setMonth(4);
  start.setFullYear(2016);
  alert(start)


  //Right  order - will return 31 May 2016
  var end = new Date();
  end.setFullYear(2016);
  end.setMonth(4);
  end.setDate(31);
  alert(end)


}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="checkDate()" />
```

This is the right heirarchy to set date.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding 1 the day position (position 1)? I think that is your problem.

```
d.setDate(dspl[1] + 1);
```