# Changing a time

Tags: datetime, google-sheets

I have a scheduling system on which several people schedule activities, by adding to a Google Sheet event_id, start_date, finish_date and start_time (HH:mm).  This goes through various validity checks, including matching start_time to a list of valid start times on another sheet.

This works.  But some of these activities are between midnight and 6am, and are therefore scheduled as belonging to the day before and sorted to the end of the daily list, not the beginning.

I do this by, for example, entering 01:30 as 25:30, which then displays as 01:30 and stores as Sunday Dec 31 1899 01:30:00, and all works as it should.

But when other people enter start times, they will often forget the instructions and enter the start time as 01:30, which does not match the validation and further processing.  What I am trying to achieve is an automatic change to such entries, such that one day is added and the system stores Sunday Dec 31 1899 01:30:00, which matches the validation.

But it doesn't.  Entering 25:30 by hand works perfectly, but entering 01:30 and then passing it to:

```
if (stime.getDay() == 6 && shr < daystart){
stime.setDate(31);
osheet.getRange(activerow,7).setValue(stime);
```

appears to work, but then does not match the validation grid.

I have tried numerous ways to add the 24 hours, such as
stime.setDate(stime.getDate()+1);
but all with the same outcome.  A manual input of 25:30 checked for equality against the appropriate cell in the validation grid returns TRUE; any computational method returns FALSE on the same test.

I am clearly doing something stupid, but what?

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: If you have found a solution on your own, please post it as an answer, so others need not engage here.

Answer (score 0):

It's always the way. Give up, ask for help, and then the answer occurs to you. There is a calculation error somewhere; the calculated value differs from the manual input from the 11th decimal place onwards. So, surrounding both parameters in the validation check with a =ROUND(stime,8) etc, will fix it. Sorry to have wasted your time. But I'll leave this here in case anybody else has a similar problem.

Comment: You said that =ROUND(stime,8) will fix the problem so Could you please write the exact values of stime before and after ROUNDING it. and one more clarification please, Are you fixing the date but taking only the time only?

Comment: Hello Mahmoud.  Yes, I'm taking the time only, not the date.

You ask the exact values of the the time variable.  In many cases they're recurring decimals and not exact; of course, Sheets can only calculate to a finite number of places.  If one, for example, enters a value of 01:10, that evaluates to 0.04861111111111110000 .  Adding 24 hours to it yields1.04861111111111000000 by one method and 1.04861111111109000000 by another; these return FALSE when compared.  In practical terms difference is negligible.  ROUND(stime,8) makes the comparison TRUE.  ROUND(stime,6) would actually be enough.

Comment: Is the date the same before AM and after AM i.e. midnight? one more thing Are you building the date in the hierarchy from the year then month then day then time Are you following this order I see this post is relative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471441/setdate-set-the-wrong-date-on-31st